# How play Google Drive Videos with JW Player or Video.js?

Tags: video-streaming, html5-video, media-player, jwplayer, video.js

I've seen some people ask this question, but none of them has ever been solved. Please suggest how to play Google Drive Videos with JW Player or Video.js or maybe there is any kind of script or WordPress Plugin to do that? Example:

```
<video class="video-js" width="640" height="264" controls preload poster="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.png">
      <source src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByaRd0R0Qyatcmw2dVhQS0NDU0U/view" type='video/mp4' />
    </video>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can use [GD Player WordPress Plugin](https://ingolin.com/)
2. Shortcodes

Google Video from Google Photos, Poster & subtitles.

```
[GDPlayer gdrive="https://photos.google.com/share/AF1QipMZZwj89FrA-m47MZE2k9A5gqPQ5VNRqnGoF59mR Qdf52zfQVmwgB1XpSaZcOVExw/photo/AF1QipMvvACIY9SuSTa-YNKm1VF0_jdUO7SZy9bGHW7M?key=UU9SV2JWNlRTTkg1aGlRVlY3TUZKbGhXMFBpNHNB" poster="https://ingolin.com/example.png"]
```

Google Drive Video, Poster & subtitles

```
[GDPlayer gdrive="https://photos.google.com/share/AF1QipMZZwj89FrA-m47MZE2k9A5gqPQ5VNRqnGoF59mR Qdf52zfQVmwgB1XpSaZcOVExw/photo/AF1QipMvvACIY9SuSTa-YNKm1VF0_jdUO7SZy9bGHW7M?key=UU9SV2JWNlRTTkg1aGlRVlY3TUZKbGhXMFBpNHNB" poster="https://ingolin.com/example.png"][track kind="captions" src="https://ingolin.com/wp-content/subtitles.vtt" srclang="en" label="English" default="true"][/GDPlayer]
```

Comment: You seem to be linking your own website and youtube video. While this is generally okay if it supports your answer and addresses the question, you have to properly disclose your affiliation with these. Otherwise your post might be treated as spam. Please have a look at [How not to be a spammer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion) and [edit] your post accordingly. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks,I thought that my answer is correct, and it is not spam, but if that is spam or ads, i can delete it, Thanks Mr.@ByteCommander

Comment: I didn't say you have to delete it, this site's policy just requires that you say that something is yours if you link to it, as detailed in the help article I mentioned above.

Comment: Thanks for your help @LeoNeLeo